# System.Data.DataSet manipulation differs between production MVC app and local app

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, pass-by-reference

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that functions much like an SSRS report - loading a System.Data.DataSet and displaying it's contents in a grid. I've used some jquery controls to allow some degree of client-side manipulation.

I have some 'actions' the user can execute against a selected item in the grid. When they click a button in the 'action panel', I formulate a web request that basically tells the WebAPI controller which System.Data.DataRow the user was working with in the UI.

The WebAPI controller doesn't just 'trust' or work directly with the posted data. Instead, it uses the postedData as a guide to go back to the model (System.Data.DataSet) and find the precise DataTable and DataRow the user had selected on their client.

*One of my 'action processing' .NET classes is giving me grief. It is supposed to update some values in the DataRow that is being passed into it.* **What could cause this? and/or How do I debug this?**

The rows are passed 'by reference' and everything works fine when I test this locally (using the Visual Studio ASP.NET Development server) - the button can be clicked, the WebAPI invokes the desired action and passes in the desired DataRow and it returns a 'success' message to the jquery ajax caller. This triggers the UI to refresh and, boom, you see the updated values on screen.

Why would this stop working in my production Windows 2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5.7600?
I've cleaned out the web app /bin and have redeployed fresh from my Visual Studio project.

---

Furthermore, I just deployed to my sandbox environment.. also a 2008 R2, IIS 7.5.7600.. and everything works just fine. If I have to do remote debugging, I would prefer to do it against ANYTHING but a production server. Ugh.. I'm open to your ideas!

---

I am dumping the server configs of my Production and Sandbox IIS environments to XML [using appcmd.exe](https://community.landesk.com/support/docs/DOC-29513) and so far, no real big differences.. both using an app pool defined with managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" and neither has any type of meaningful difference in their site configuration...

SANDBOX:

```
<location path="my.test.dataApp - 96">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
                    <providers>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                        <add value="Negotiate" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

PRODUCTION:

```
<location path="wq.ross.local">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
                    <providers>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                        <add value="Negotiate" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

---

*There are yet **more** baffling wrinkles to this problem:*
The issue only seems to manifest itself on a particular DataSet.. if I navigate to a different 'viewer' on my app (i.e. if I pass a different parameter to the same controller action) that loads up a test System.Data.DataSet, and if I click a button wired to the same type of 'action' .NET class.. it *does* effectively update the selected System.Data.DataRow.. and so, for this particular *test* DataSet - there is no issue on DEV, SANDBOX or PRODUCTION.. but for my other DataSet - it only works in DEV and SANDBOX, but not PRODUCTION (all three environments are currently loading their DataSets from the same production DB source)

Comment: Are you getting a particular error in production or are you simply not seeing the expected behavior?

Comment: There is no error. I'm simply not seeing the expected behavior. if there was an error, I would expect it to affect the ajax request - but it completes and returns successfully.

Comment: Are you building in DEBUG mode for DEV and SANDBOX, but RELEASE for production? Are you using bundling and minification for your JS?

Comment: Right now, I've turned off bundling/minification on all servers. My SANDBOX and RELEASE servers are in 'RELEASE' mode. I only run in DEBUG mode, currently, for my DEV build.

Comment: I would add some logging to make sure your action method is really getting called.  Maybe something is wrong in the MVC routing. Next, add more detailed logging to lines in your action to make sure the expected code paths are being hit.  There could be an exception being thrown and somewhere an exception handler that eats the exception.  Finally, I check things like file permissions and so on.

Comment: I think that your "baffling wrinkles" might offer a clue as to what's going on. My theory is that something in PRODUCTION is filtering the request (for security reasons), and that such filtering is absent from the other two server environments. You say earlier in the question that rows are passed 'by reference'. Try manually comparing the references (presumably UIDs) for a dataset that works with those of a datset that doesn't. Are there any systematic differences - presence of upper-case characters, non-alphanumeric characters etc etc?

Comment: @KC-NH - I just got the EventLog wired up and have put in hooks at the appropriate junctures. Will post back my findings

Comment: I would start first by doing this: In Chrome press F12 and then click the network tab to see the posted information.  You'll see a "Get" or "Post" request that you can click on and see the formmated "Form" data.  Compare a working example to a failing example, any differences will lead you to which side to focus.  If inbound request is same on both sides, then the problem lay in a "State Machine" on the server api side.  If Inbound requests are different then problem is on client side.

Comment: No luck folks. I put in some event log messaging to see what the controller was actually doing. I can see on the server that the posted JSON object is correctly parsed into a JArray (lets say for a given request the JArray's length is 5, representing 5 data rows) and I can see through the event log that the JArray is being further parsed into a .NET FilterExpression string that I then pass into a DataTable.Select() method.. and is successfully selecting the correct/desired number of DataRows (@John Peters - thanks for the contribution, but, I've now ruled out the browser/UI layer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, there is still no real answer to what is actually causing my problem. I never specifically figured out the technical issue that was causing my particular DataSet operation to fail on one specific 'PRODUCTION' instance of Windows 2008 R2, while the same application code, working on the same DataSet, worked bug-free on my 'SANDBOX' instance of Windows 2008 R2.

However, I am posting my final findings and workaround.

In my OP, I described in some detail how my DataSet viewer MVC/WebAPI solution worked as expected on my local workstation and my SANDBOX 2008 R2, but failed consistently (but.. only on a particular DataSet) in my PRODUCTION 2008 R2 server.

Since that post, I've discovered one difference between my SANDBOX and PRODUCTION environments. SANDBOX had a .NET Framework 4.5.x installed, whereas PRODUCTION was only running .NET Framework 4.

At the time, this was an MVC 4 solution - so - I don't believe having 4.5 installed was even a requirement. But, for whatever reason, my MVC 4 solution ran better on the server (and local workstation) that had the 4.5 framwork installed. So.. to me.. the solution was straightforward:

My solution was to ask my network admin to provision a new 2008 R2 server. I built out the IIS and upp'd the .NET Framework to 4.5.5 (and went ahead and upgraded my solution to MVC5/WebApi2 while I was at it) - now everything just works.